# How to make delegate of ListView change its size when view's parent is resized?

Tags: qt, listview, qml, qtquick2

I followed the Qt 5.2 documentation on ListView (http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#details). My code is almost identical to the doc except for the contactDelegate's width which I want to bind to the width of the Rectangle listArea.

When I run the code below it looks as expected. However, when I resize the window the delegate is not resized with the rectangle's changing width.

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    id: listArea
    width: 200; height: 50
    color: "#fffcca"

    Component {
        id: contactDelegate
        Item {
            width: listArea.width; height: 40
            Column {
                Text { text: '<b>Name:</b> ' + name }
                Text { text: '<b>Number:</b> ' + number }
            }
        }
    }

    ListModel {
        id: contactModel
        ListElement {
            name: "John Doe"
            number: "5555 1234"
        }
        ListElement {
            name: "Don Johnson"
            number: "5555 5432"
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: contactView
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: contactModel
        delegate: contactDelegate
        highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5 }
        focus: true
    }
}
```

How can I make the delegate's width adapt to changing width of the outer rectangle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is already changing width with outer rectangle. Because the delegate's width property is already bound to the width of `listArea`. But the problem is that the `highlight` in `contactView` isn't changing it's width. 
This could be fixed by bounding the width property in the `highlight` of contact view to be bound to the width of `listArea` like the `contactDelegate` which would make it something like this

```
highlight: Rectangle { color: "lightsteelblue"; radius: 5; width: listArea.width }
```

here is a like to the documentation about property binding
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/propertybinding.html